# IndexedDB: How to prevent long int type being stored as string?

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexeddb

The `IndexedDB` has weird behaviour. When I tried to store `long` int number, it is stored as `string`. This will mess up the indexing, especially when I want to sort the data.

Example:

```
const data: {
  id: string,
  dateCreated: (new Date()).valueOf() //this is long type milliseconds
}
```

It is stored as `"1674874732259"` string inside the `IndexedDB`.

How do I prevent this?

---

This Is How I Store The Data

I use `idb` library to do it, write the async function much neater:

```
  async upsert(data: Note) {
    try {
      const db = await this.dbPromise;
      const tx = db.transaction(this.tableName, 'readwrite');
      const store = tx.objectStore(this.tableName);
      store.put(data);
      await tx.done;
    } catch (err) {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```

---

DETAILED

```
  export const millisecondsNow = () => new Date().valueOf();

  async createNew() {
    const now = millisecondsNow();

    const newNote = {
      id: generateUUID(),
      title: 'Untitled',
      content: '',
      dateCreated: now,
      lastUpdated: now,
      status: 'ACTIVE',
      tags: '',
      userId: this.auth.auth.value.id,
    } as Note;

    await this.db.note.upsert(newNote);
    this.addList(newNote);
    this.sync.pushToSyncOutQueue(newNote);
  }

  async upsert(data: Note) {
    try {
      const db = await this.dbPromise;
      const tx = db.transaction(this.tableName, 'readwrite');
      const store = tx.objectStore(this.tableName);
      store.put(data);
      await tx.done;
    } catch (err) {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```

This is the data stored in the database:

[image: DATABASE]

Note that the last entry is number, this is because my application sync-in a note from a `Node` server which has number type as the `lastUpdated` type. Somehow saving the incoming data from my server makes the `lastUpdated` column into number type.

Assigning the `lastUpdated` and `dateCreated` with `0` (number) will save the data successfully. It has a number type.

---

DEBUGGING SCREENSHOT

See this screenshot:

[image: Debug screenshot]

Look at the value of the `newNote` at the right side of the image, inside the scope. This is the state of the object just before saving into the database. The `lastUpdated` and `dateCreated` are numbers.

Comment: Can you please show how you are storing that `data` object in your indexedDB? I really doubt this happens by itself.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'long' data type in Javascript. It will be stored as a number, which is IEEE 754 floating point. If you provide a full code sample that puts and then retrieves it, we'll probably observe a bug in your code somewhere which is casting it to a string

Comment: I use debugger to even see the `dateCreated` value right before the `.put()` from `idb`, the value is still a number. But in the database the value is changed into string. This is not the case when I just assign the dateCreated with `0` number, it is stored as number. This is so confusing. Maybe is it because I use `idb` library, maybe it has bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the `millisecondsNow()` method into this:

```
export const millisecondsNow = () => +(new Date().valueOf());
```

By adding `+` sign which make sure that this returns number. To be honest I do not know how this solution even works. The `new Date().valueOf()` is already returning number.

Maybe someone can explain.

Comment: This makes no sense. You can use `typeof` to see that `new Date().valueOf()` is of type 'number'. The problem must be elsewhere. Post a self-contained example of this failing (when you're not using `+`) when the value is retrieved from the db

Comment: Yes it does not make any sense, but I did not change anything only adding the + sign. It works perfectly now. I am also confused about this and I cannot explain in detail what was happening.